# Why my esp8266 timer did not function

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I try to do a little timer on my NodeMCU v3.

I want to set a time in milliseconds after that the led should go on.
And when I set a new time it should go off.

```
unsigned long times;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  times = 0;

}

void loop() {

  while(Serial.available()==0){}
  times=Serial.parseInt();
  times=times+ millis();
  Serial.print(times);
  Serial.println(" Millis");

  if (millis() > times )
  {
    digitalWrite(2, LOW); 
  } else {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  }
}
```

The led goes off and not on again
It is low active.

Answer (score 0):

`while(Serial.available()==0){}`
This line says: execute the code between the brackets als long as there's no data on Serial.

And if you do type something on Serial, the code would execute once. Depending on the value of millis(), which can overflow, the led would be on our off.

So you've got to get your logic right!